# How do I input bar-chart data to an overall pie-chart ? (Highcharts/ JS / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Very new to all this; I'm stuck in implementing the jQuery of a Highcharts pie-chart. Each of the bar-charts are built with radio button inputs and there are float values associated with each input. These values then sum to build the bar-chart. I'm trying to build it with sum-totals taken from three seperate bar-charts. Any help would be massively appreciated. Here's a jsfiddle I knocked up, just please expand the run window to maximum

**HTML**

```
        <div class="" id="meansTransport" >
                               <ul>
                                    <p id="boxTitle">Means of transport</p>
                                    <input type="radio" id="question-means-A" name="test" value="0.0" />
                                    <label for="question-means-A"> I almost always go by public transport, cycle or walk</label><br>
                                    <input type="radio" id="question-means-B" name="test" value="1.4"  />
                                    <label for="question-means-B"> I use the car and public transport about the same amount</label><br>
                                    <input type="radio" id="question-means-C" name="test" value="1.8" />
                                    <label for="question-means-C"> I almost always drive by car</label><br>
                                </ul>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5" id="graphMobility"></div>
```

**Highcharts/ (1st of 3) bar-charts**

The totals would be taken from each of three bar-charts eg. 'mobilityTotal'

```
    var graphMobility = Highcharts.chart('graphMobility', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        backgroundColor: "#fafafa", 
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Per capita CO2 emissions',
        color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
        data: [2.5, 3.1, 2.2, 1.6],
        pointPadding: -0.2,
        pointPlacement: 0.0
    }, {
        name: 'Personal CO2 footprint', 
        opacity: 0.9,
        borderWidth: 3, 
        borderColor:'white',
        dashStyle: 'ShortDot', 
        data: [0.0],
        pointPadding: -0.2,
        pointPlacement: 0.0
        }]
    });


    var sum = 0;


    $("#mobilityBox input:radio").click(function() {
       sum = 0.8;

        $("#mobilityBox input:radio:checked").each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseFloat(elm.value, 10);
        });

        var mobilityTotal = sum;

        graphMobility.series[1].setData([sum], true);

      });
    });
```

**Highcharts/pie-chart**

This is where the bar-chart totals should add, and be adapted into the pie-chart. I've been reading through potential solutions but nothing seems to hold at all. This is what I have that still definitely works.

```
        var circlePie = Highcharts.chart('circlePie', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false, 
        backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Household: 3t <br> Total: 11t ', 
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 35, 
        style: {
                fontSize: '3.1vh',
                color: '#404040', 
                fontWeight: '600', 
                lineHeight: '45', 
                fontFamily: 'Verdana'
            }
    },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',

    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                distance: 0,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white',
                }
            },
            startAngle: -35,
            endAngle: -36,
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
            size: '100%'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Emissions share',
        innerSize: '53%',
        data: [
            ['Mobility', 28.9],
            ['Food', 23.29],
            ['Household', 33],
        ]
    }]
    });
```

So, what I'm trying to do is take the bar-chart sum-data eg. "mobilityTotal" and input it into the, above, pie-chart -- series data array [0] 'Mobility'. This question will probably be really basic. And the jsfiddle again, just please expand the run window to maximum

Comment: You started fine, just an error in event binding, when fixed [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/wxj7f2hz/9/)... adding one value (should be array for more). So, just replace `$("#mobilityBox input:radio").click` to `$("#meansTransport input:radio").click` .... even better, do not use click, but `change` event and `$(this).val()` to get the selected value.

Comment: Hey there, checked your solution out and all it seems to do is change how the Highcharts bar-chart behaves, it only builds forward; the user can't change the selection

Comment: Hi @isntlee, Could you describe more precisely what values you want to show in the `pie` chart? Could you also add the rest of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4701/ ?

Comment: Hey man, done: https://jsfiddle.net/Isntlee/f1hw0ty6/6/ (you'll have to expand the viewing window to max). The plan is to take the totals from each bar-chart (aka personal data or light blue coloured graph data) and input it into the pie-chart. Then to write an expression that would change the centre text in the pie-chart to display the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is update the right point on the `pie` chart. For example:

```
$("#mobilityBox input:radio").click(function() {
  ...

  circlePie.series[0].points[0].update({
    y: sum
  });
  graphMobility.series[1].setData([sum], true);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v458b67q/6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: You're a star mate, and, of course, I've questions. Tell me if you don't mind

Comment: Sure, I will try to help you :)

Comment: The only question I have is how would I change the details in the centre of the pie-chart, I just don't know the syntax/statement. (Total ) This should be a total of all the sums and the detail above it should be the mousehover function but it should show what the sum is for that graph eg household

Comment: Other than that, all I can do is say, thanks, this has been really frustrating.

Comment: You need to change the `title` property, for example by using `setTitle` method: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setTitle